# Compactness of $(x_1,x_2,...)\mapsto(0,x_1,x_2/2...)$

Tags: spectral-theory, compact-operators

I read that the linear operator in the Hilbert space $\ell_2$ defined by $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)\mapsto(0,x_1,x_2/2,...,x_n/n,...)$ is compact.

I wanted to prove it by proving that the image of the closed unit sphere is totally limited, but I am not sure that is the right path and I am getting nothing...

Moreover, I would like to learn to find its spectrum, but my book does not give examples about how to find it...

$\infty$ thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you considered repeated application of this operator?

Comment: @hardmath how does that help?

Comment: The end of the Question expresses an interest in the operator's spectrum (eigenvalues).  It is evident from considering the repeated application of the operator that no nonzero eigenvalue is possible.  It's also possible to show compactness by bounding the operator squared.

Comment: Thank you so much, hardmath! I am able to prove to myself that it has no eigenvector, no 0 eigenvalues, but I'm not able to find the continuous spectrum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $\{x(0,i)\}_{i=1}^\infty = (x_1(0,i),x_2(0,i),\dots)$ be an arbitrary sequence in the unit ball.

For all $n \geq 0$, let $\{x(n+1,i)\}_{i=1}^\infty = (x_1(n+1,i),x_2(n+1,i),\dots)$, be a subsequence of $\{x(n,i)\}_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $\{x_{n+1}(n+1,i)\}_{i=1}^\infty$ converges.

Now, consider the subsequence $\{x(i,i)\}_{i=1}^\infty$ of our original sequence. Note that this sequence converges in each coordinate.

Define 
$$
T(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...) = (0,x_1,x_2/2,...,x_n/n,...)
$$
and show (with an appropriate $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument) that $\{Tx(i,i)\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy (or that it converges) with respect to the $\ell^2$ norm.

Comment: Forgive me: what is $\{x_{n+1}(n+1,i)\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and how do we know that there is such a convergent sequence? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Perhaps this will clear it up: $\{x(1,i)\}$ is a subsequence such that the first coordinate, $\{x_1(1,i)\}$, converges.  We can do this because $\{x_1(0,i)\}_{i}$, the sequence of the first coordinate of our sequence, is a bounded real sequence.  $\{x(2,i)\}_i$ is a subsequence of our original such that $\{x_1(2,-i)\}_{i}$ *and* $\{x_2(2,i)\}_i$ converge.  The pattern continues.

Comment: Very kind, I think everything is clear now: $\|T(x(i,i))-T(\{\lim_{k}x_n(n,k)\}_{n})\|^2$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{x_n(i,i)}{n}-\frac{\lim_{k}x_n(n,k)}{n}|^2\xrightarrow{i\to\infty}0$. $n$ thanks with $n\to\infty$! ;-)OK, I didn't see what the index $_{n+1}$ meant :-s

Comment: You should be careful in showing that this sum approaches zero.  In particular, why can't I use this trick to prove that the identity operator is compact?

Comment: Thank you so much again!!! I thought that $\forall n\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}^{+}:\forall i\geq N\quad|x_{n}(i,i)-\lim_k x_n(n,k)|<\epsilon$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{x_n(i,i)}{n}-\frac{\lim_{k}x_n(n,k)}{n}|^2<\epsilon \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2} =\pi^2\epsilon/6$, but I'm no longer sure of the "$\forall n$"...

Comment: I would try the bound $x_n(i,i) - \lim_k x_n(k,k) \leq 1$ when $n \leq N(\epsilon)$ and $x_n(i,i) - \lim_k x_n(k,k) \leq \epsilon$ when $n \geq N(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm not understanding: why is $|x_n(i,i)−\lim_k x_n(k,k)|\leq 1$ when $n\leq N(\epsilon)$ and why $|x_n(i,i)−\lim_k x_n(k,k)|\leq\epsilon$ when $n\geq N(\epsilon)$? Is this $N(\epsilon)$ related to the $N'(\epsilon)$ such that $\forall n≥N′(\varepsilon)\quad|x_n(i,i)−\lim_k x_n(k,k)|<ϵ$? $\aleph_1$ thanks!

Comment: I hope I've understood... There is an $N=N(\epsilon)$ such that $\forall i\geq N\quad |x_n(i,i)-\lim_k x_n(k,k)|<\epsilon$. Then $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|x_n(i,i)-\lim_k x_n(k,k)|^2/n^2<\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\epsilon^2/n^2$. For the same reason there is an $M=M(\epsilon,N(\epsilon))$ suh that $\forall n<N$ $\forall i\geq M\quad |x_n(i,i)-\lim_k x_n(k,k)|<\epsilon$ and therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}|x_n(i,i)-\lim_k x_n(k,k)|^2/n^2<\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\epsilon^2/n^2$. Chosing $i\geq\max\{N(\epsilon),M(\epsilon,N(\epsilon))\}$ the sum is $<\pi^2\epsilon^2/6$. I Hope not to be too wrong. $\aleph_1$ thanks!!!